# Wordpress create shortcode from javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode from a piece of javascript code in order to allow me to call the javascript within a certain place on my page.

The javascript is relatively simple and works (Displaying a countdown timer). However it doesn't get called correctly on my front end when attempting to shortcode it.

Below is my steps and code produced...any suggestions on how to get this displayed correctly would be appreciated!

**Javascript code for `date_counter` function:**

```
// The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'date_counter' );
function date_counter() {
    ?>
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("July 29, 2018 09:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Display the result in the element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

// If the count down is finished, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
</script>
    <?php
}
```

**Here is the PHP function where I am trying to initialise the `date_counter` function as a shortcode:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('datecountershortcode', 'date_counter');
}
```

**Here is how I am calling the final shortcode on my wordpress page to try and display the counter**

```
[datecountershortcode]
```

Attempting to call the above shortcode doesn't work and just displays the shortcode text. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Registering a shortcode in this case is redundant. You have already registered the script in the footer and it should be present on all non-dashboard pages.

Comment: Yes @RWS Is completely right…

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call "date_counter" when you add the shortcode.  You're javascript is looking for an element with and id of "demo" so you need a separate shortcode function that will put that on the page for you.  Try this.

```
function datecountershortcode_func( $atts ) {
    return '<div id="demo"></div>';
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('datecountershortcode', 'datecountershortcode_func');
}
```